# Regression slope question

Tags: regression, linear-model

Suppose there are $n$ feature vectors $X_1, ...X_n$ which predict $Y$. Suppose we linear regress $X_1$ on $Y$, $X_2$ on $Y$ and so on and obtain all positive slopes $\beta_1>0, \beta_2>0,..\beta_n >0$. Now we perform multiple linear regression $Y = \sum_i\beta_iX_i$, and estimate slopes $\beta_i$, is it necessary that all $\beta_i>0$?

I am looking for a rigorous proof of why it is not necessary $\beta_i>0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Do your regressions include an intercept or not?

Comment: @whuber No. But for completeness, I would also like to know how the answer would change if intercept is included.

Comment: Consider the observations of $(x_1,x_2,y)$ given by $(1,2,4),$ $(0,2,5),$ and $(0,0,1).$  This provides a counterexample with an intercept. For a counterexample without an intercept, include a third variable $x_3$ constantly equal to $1.$

Comment: @whuber Do you have any rigorous proof instead of example?

Comment: An example, in this case, *is* a rigorous proof according to the very highest mathematical standards.

Comment: @whuber I agree. Perhaps the better question would have been an intuitive explanation on why slopes don't have to be all positive?

Comment: You can find that explained in several threads here on multiple regression.  Look for answers that sport geometric diagrams, because they present the essence of the issue, which is purely geometric.  The idea is that when all the explanatory vectors make acute angles with each other, the response $y$ can fall outside their positive cone while still having a positive projection on each of those vectors individually.

Comment: @titanium see the wikipedia articles on *omitted variable bias* and on *Simpson's paradox* (especially the diagram near the start).

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is no:** the univariate regressions can all have positive coefficients, yet the multiple regression can involve negative coefficients.

**You ask for intuition.**  One route to that is through the geometric interpretation of the Ordinary Least Squares solution, as expressed by the Normal equations: they state that the coefficients in the regression of a column of $n$ data $y$ on explanatory columns $x_i$ are the coefficients of the orthogonal projection of the *vector* $y$ onto the span of the *vectors* $x_i$ in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $R^n.$

Although $n$ dimensions sounds like a lot, **you don't need more than two dimensions to visualize useful examples:** just limit yourself to $2$ explanatory variables $x_1$ and $x_2.$  *They* determine a plane (at least when they're not collinear) and we may suppose $y$ is located in that very plane.

Here, to illustrate, is a situation where $y= x_1 - x_2.$  As indicated at the bottom right, although these vectors "live" in $R^n,$ we can draw them faithfully within the plane of the paper.

[image: Figure]

The gray area at the left is the locus of points whose projection onto *some* of the $x_i$ has a negative coefficient.  It's the union of all the half-planes behind the $x_i.$  Provided $y$ lies outside that gray area, its regression (*i.e.*, projection) onto any of the variables $x_i$ *individually* is guaranteed to have a *positive* value.  Nevertheless, whenever $y$ is outside the infinite wedge lying between the $x_1$ and $x_2$ direction (their positive cone $\{\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2\mid \alpha\ge 0, \beta\ge 0 \}$), it (obviously) cannot have all its coefficients positive. That leaves great scope for counterexamples.

Comment: For an extended discussion of these relationships see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223948/919.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let's do a simulation to develop a counterexample.

```
set.seed(2021)
library(MASS)
N <- 100
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.95, 0.95, 1), 2, 2))
x1 <- X[, 1]
x2 <- X[, 2]
y <- x1 - x2 + rnorm(N)
L1 <- lm(y ~ x1)
L2 <- lm(y ~ x2)
L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
```

This happens if you tack on `+ 0` in the `lm` calls to indicate that the intercept should be excluded, too.

```
set.seed(2021)
library(MASS)
N <- 100
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.95, 0.95, 1), 2, 2))
x1 <- X[, 1]
x2 <- X[, 2]
y <- x1 - x2 + rnorm(N)
L1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + 0)
L2 <- lm(y ~ x2 + 0)
L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + 0)
```

However, the usual advice is to include an intercept unless you have a good reason not to.