# Use X1 to predict Y, the correlation is 0.1, use X2 the correlation is 0.2, what is the range of correlation if combine X1 and X2

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation

For linear regression, if use X1 alone to predict Y, the correlation is 0.1, use X2 the correlation is 0.2, what is the range of correlation if combine X1 and X2. Assume that X1 and X2 are independent.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: For effective methods of solving this problem, see the closely related questions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305441, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550810.

Comment: @qwerty1010 .... also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122888/how-to-infer-correlations-from-correlations/ There's probably several more to be found