# If X is positively correlated with Y and Y is positively correlated with Z, it is still possible for Z to be negatively correlated with X?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, pearson-r, variable

This is not assuming a perfect correlation between variables. I believe that the answer is yes as long as r<1.0. (r =  Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient.)

Bonus: if the question is false at certain correlation coefficients, at what correlation coefficient does this begin to occur?

Comment: I'm not sure. I recall a paper in the 2000s showed that $r_{xy}^2 + r_{yz}^2 > 1 \implies r_{xz}^2 > 0$ but that is a very weak condition and doesn't answer your question.

Comment: (1) Are you assuming *positive* correlations between $X$ and $Y$ and between $Y$ and $Z$? (2) Which correlation coefficient are you looking at?

Comment: @StephanKolassa (1) Good catch; thank you; fixed. (2) Pearson's r.

Comment: I am sure this has been addressed in several threads.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790/bound-for-the-correlation-of-three-random-variables for one account where the correlation coefficients $\rho_{XY}$ and $\rho_{YZ}$ are equal and positive.  Likely most of the posts I remember are in a regression context, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223948/919.  A glance at the figures in the latter will reveal what's going on: vectors $X$ and $Z$ can make acute angles with $Y,$ yet make an obtuse angle with each other.  Examples are easy to construct.

Comment: @whuber I don't see how that question is answered in the linked threads. Do you think those other threads say "yes" or "no" to the present question?

Comment: I assume you're interested in mathematical proof but if not, you can try this empirically yourself by generating data with different correlation structures (e.g. using R MASS package function mvrnorm). I tried some and rs=0.5 / -0.5 worked, rs 0.6 / -0.6 didn't. Of course, there are different correlation strength combinations you can try.

Comment: Start simulating $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ until you find a triplet that provides a counterexample. Easiest to do for small vectors, e.g., of length 3. I was writing up the answer with the counterexample here when @whuber closed the thread...

Comment: My post in the duplicate thread *explicitly constructs* counterexamples, so yes, it provides a definitive yes/no answer.

Comment: @sointu A very general solution is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305441.  The present question is resolved quantitatively with the determinant-derived bound given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747. In that post I also specifically answer the present question negatively in terms of the *Spearman* correlation which, because it is the Pearson correlation of ranks. also provides an answer here.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. That thread (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/if-a-and-b-are-correlated-with-c-why-are-a-and-b-not-necessarily-correlated) has information that can be used to answer the question. (The answer is "yes.") Then, the formula to determine this is (r^2 between X and Y)+(r^2 between Y and Z) must be < 1 for X and Z to have a negative correlation, I think.

Comment: Right.  Assuming the XY and YZ correlations are positive, that criterion is equivalent to the angle criterion I gave in my first comment.

Comment: The answer to the bonus is r = 0.70710678118 (assuming the same correlation). 1/sqrt(2). (50% variance explained). I wonder how to calculate this if I want a certain negative correlation, say, r = 0.15, between X and Z instead of r = 0.

Comment: The bonus question is unclear, because there are *two* original correlation coefficients: $\rho_{XY}$ and $\rho_{YZ}.$ But almost any version of it is easy to answer using the angle interpretation.  For instance, with $\rho_{XZ}=-0.15,$ the necessary criterion for $\rho_{XZ}\le -0.15$ is $\cos(\arccos(\rho_{XY})+\arccos(\rho_{YZ}))\le -0.15.$